# Does JPA's optimistic locking know to cycle to zero after Long.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a class which is updated quite frequently and I'm using JPA's optimistic locking via:

```
  @Version
  public long getVersion() {
    return version;
  }
```

I'm watching the value get pretty large on my test systems and am nervous about production.  Does JPA (I'm using hibernate) handle going across the Long.MAX_VALUE value or is this something I need to handle myself?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: How large the current value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JPA spec doesn't mention about what will be the behavior when it reaches the maximum value for the version column. I did a bit of testing to see how this behaves.

In Java, `Long.MAX_VALUE` is equivalent to: `9223372036854775807`

I tested with MySQL as my database. According to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html), `BIGINT` which maps to Java's `java.util.Long` type also has the same maximum value: `9223372036854775807`

In Java, when you increment `Long.MAX_VALUE` and print the result, you'll get `-9223372036854775808`, which is equivalent to `Long.MIN_VALUE`. So we can say, that Java cycles back to the minimum value once it reaches beyond the maximum value. The minimum value for MySQL `BIGINT` is also the same as Java's: `-9223372036854775808`

So here's how I tested using JPA:

I initially created a `TestEntity` with the ff. code:

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private Long version;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

Notice, I first did not annotated the version field with `@Version` so I can manually set to the maximum value for `Long`. Now, I tried persisting a new `TestEntity` to MySQL DB. Using the following code:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();    
TestEntity test = new TestEntity();
test.setName("test");
test.setVersion(Long.MAX_VALUE); // manually set the version to the maximum value
em.persist(test);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I manually set the version field to Long's maximum value. As expected in MySQL database, here's what I got from my table:

```
1 | test | 9223372036854775807
```

Now, I updated the `TestEntity` code. This time, I have annotated the version field with `@Version`.

@Entity
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
@Version
private Long version;
private String name;
...
```

}

Then, I created a new code to find the `TestEntity` that was created previously and update its name:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
TestEntity testEntity = em.find(TestEntity.class, 1);
testEntity.setName("changed");
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Surprisingly, I did not get an error saying I've reached the maximum value. Instead, entity was successfully updated. Here's what I have in my table:

```
1 | changed | -9223372036854775808
```

You see, it did cycle back to the minimum value. I'd assume that JPA doesn't currently have the mechanism to prevent reaching the maximum value. It actually just uses Java's default behavior of cycling back to the minimum, once max value has been reached.

Comment: since you've already gone this far... can you try updating the version one more time?  (wondering if it handles the negative number)

Comment: It does. It actually incremented to -9223372036854775807